# Code/text folding in SWING

Tags: java, swing, folding

I'm looking for a way to provide 'text folding' capabilities to a swing JTextArea or JTextPane

More specifically, I want to add a block of data in a text component and I want the component to display only some header line. Then the user can unfold the block by clicking some icon. This is just like the code folding feature in most IDE.

I've found [->some sample code<-](http://java-sl.com/collapse_area.html) after some thorough search, but the mechanisms used here are quite obscure to me and it stops working when I try to remove text from the document.

Maybe using XML as input could be a lead ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Maybe using XML as input could be a lead"? Are you writing to display XML in an expandable view? If yes, I would think of using a `JTree` rather than a text component.

Comment: No sorry, I don't need multi-level documents, I just thought that some markup could help determine what part of the text is a foldable section.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at the NetBeans API: http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-editor-fold/overview-summary.html

If you were to do it yourself, you'd need to provide a `Document` implementation that makes the `JTextComponent` think that pieces are being added or removed, then attach click events that tell the document to update itself. A lot of work.

Visually, it may also be better to use `JEditorPane`, but that's probably more work.