# How can I create collapsible text using Scala Swing

Tags: user-interface, scala, text, scala-swing, collapsable

I simply need to have collapsible text in my Scala application. I am already using the Swing wrapper. Each block of text is stored in it's own object. I just need help finding out how to add the collapsible icons and features via Swing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scala Swing's purpose is mainly to cut down on the ridiculous amount of boilerplate and guff required in Java Swing: don't expect major new functionality. Since Java Swing doesn't have collapsible text, Scala Swing doesn't either. You'll need to find a 3rd party library. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663335/code-text-folding-in-swing